# Rome 2 Total War Campaign Turn Limit

Tags: rome-2-total-war

Does the grand campaign in Rome 2 Total War have a turn limit, or is it open ended until one faction fulfills its victory conditions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that there is no hard limit to the number turns you can have in the grand campaign.

However, I don't think I've had a campaign last more than about 200 turns. If you actually work towards doing anything, you'll eventually either reach the campaign objectives or be destroyed -- so I think there's somewhat of a natural limit there, rather than one imposed by the system.

Answer (score 0):

There is technically a turn limit. After 300 years the game "ends" but gives you the option to keep on playing. Also, I believe the scripted events stop occurring.